# Is it possible to extract lines from a .docx document?

Tags: java, python, .net, ms-word

Is it possible to extract lines from a .docx document?

I don't mean the lines as created by the user when pressing '\n', I mean the lines in the .docx as they appear when opening the file (i.e., the soft text wrapping).

My preference would be doing this in Python (I am aware of the .docx Python library but I don't think it does the trick). However, any programming language is welcome as long as it provides me with what I want.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can loop through it by reading the bytes, but it's pretty incomprehensible: https://pastebin.com/nKe0rySF . If you want it in text, you can use a library for that, but you said you wanted the wrapper.

Comment: I cant quite catch it. Extract the lines of a word document into what? you want to see them in python? you want to save them in txt?

Comment: I would think that it should be possible with Apache POI. Take a look at that project

Comment: Apache POI libraries will read your DOCSX files https://poi.apache.org/document/index.html

Comment: @Gabor & E.S: Thank you guys for your comments. Unfortunately apache POI extracts paragraphs, that consist of text elements - as far as I can tell there is no apparent way of extracting lines from .docx using apache POI.

Comment: @ nfn neil & Ethan: Thank you both, yes, I need it in text.

Comment: @Alex: it should be possible. I have seen examples, where a docx was converted into image. That is only possible if the wrapping is known.

Comment: @Gabor: I believe so as well, but does that mean that I will have to replicate the rendering algorithm that MS Word runs when displaying the lines? I hope that this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem/question properly but I was dealing with same problem for a few week. I've succeeded to parse docx file to a txt file line by line as it was. I hope this piece of code works for you too.
Sorry for my limited knowledge about writing in English.

```
public class parseDocx {
public static void parse(String src,String dest) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
        XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dest);
        String[] Linelist = extractor.getText().split("[\\r?\\n]+");
        for(String str : Linelist){
            fw.write(str + "\r\n");
        }
        fw.flush();
        fis.close();
        fw.close();
        System.out.println(extractor.getText());
    }catch(IOException | InvalidFormatException ex) {} 
}
```

Above in the code you can delete the system.out line and src stands for source file's directory and dest stands for destination file's directory.